# Изъятие данных из таблицы с помощью выделения мыши

Tags: html, css, python, flask

Суть проблемы в том, что я создал с помощью Flask страницу с таблицей, далее мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь выделил правой кнопкой мыши группу ячеек в одном столбце(не весь столбец) и данный массив ячеек отправился на сервер.
Никак не могу понять как это воссоздать. Просьба хотя бы подсказать технологию. Можно ли это сделать на Flask или CSS или надо подключать Javaskript.

(также желательно выделение групп ячеек в нескольких столбцах через ПРАВАЯ КНОПКА МЫШИ + CTRL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Левая кнопка мыши отметит + `ctrl` сообщение выдаст отмеченный текст, с отправкой уже можно `Ajax`. Технологии: `jQuery+JavaScript`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('table').mouseup(function(event) { // Левая кнопка мыши 
    if (event.ctrlKey) { // CRTL+Left Click
      // Все что отмечено
      var selObj = window.getSelection();
      window.alert(selObj.toString()); // Принт строки
    }
  });

});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```